# Get all values from table using where operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble trying to retrieve all records from my table where the user ID isn't equal to that of the session id, and where value in column X is greater than that of column Y. I'd like to return my results in a loop.

My code so far is...

```
// Select all users that arent the current session users and have a 
// higher integer in bank column than that of the credits column

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id!=? AND user_bank <= user_credits');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Return all records in a loop
```

How can I accomplish this?

---

**Error Log**

```
[Wed May 29 21:08:49 2013] [error] [client 89.240.62.228] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''19497918' AND user_bank <= user_credits' at line 1' in ...
```

Comment: I currently receive a 500 server error @PhilCross and I'm unaware of the NOT operator, thanks for suggesting it

Comment: Check your error log. My guess is that there will be something like `trying to execute prepare() on a non-object` OR the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks @IanBrindley, Ive added my error log - user_bank and user_credits are columns in my table

Comment: @Liam I have seen this before with PARAM_INT, try type casting `$uid` in the bindParam call. (`bindParam(1, (int)$uid, PDO::PARMA_INT)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will be something like:

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    print_r( $row );
}
```

---

It is considered good practice to select *known* columns from table. Also, you can use `<>` for inequality operator.

```
SELECT user_id, user_bank, user_credits
FROM users 
WHERE user_id <> ? 
    AND user_bank <= user_credits
```

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work @hjpotter92, user_bank and user_credits are column in my table, so is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: @Liam Can you provide the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it.

Put a loop around `$row` assignment.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   //do something
}
```

Or, just use `fetchAll()` and then loop on it. (This is bad for large databases)

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to my comments...

After seeing this before with PDO::PARAM_INT the solution I have used in the past is to type cast your variable like so:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id!=? AND user_bank <= user_credits');
$stmt->bindParam(1, (int)$uid, PDO::PARAM_INT); // <-- here
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```